# Automatically update text in Visio diagrams

Tags: scripting, visio

I have build several Visio diagrams and posted them on my web server as .htm. Now I would like to make a script that update the values of the labels on the in the shapes automatically once on every hour from  a file with data (.csv or .txt). Is there a way to automatically pull those values and put them in the .htm file of the visio diagram?

Answer (score 1):

Visio shapes can be linked to an external data source. Just replace the fixed text on the shape with fields that refer to the shape data. Take a look at http://office.microsoft.com/en-ca/visio-help/demo-show-it-like-it-is-connect-data-to-your-visio-diagram-HA010051819.aspx